# Document Library level auditing in SP 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, auditing

I want to enable auditing on one of the document library for "Change" event.

My question is, Is it mandatory to enable "Editing Items" from site collection settings for audits to be generated or enabling auditing in the "Information Management Policy Settings" from document library settings is sufficient?

If I enable it at the site collection level, all the EDIT events are getting logged. I want it only for particular document library. Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to enable auditing for the site collection to be able to use auditing at the document library or list level. That is the whole point of it, that you can just audit the specific library/list, without getting flooded by the audit events for the whole site collection.

For more information on this, you can check this blog [How to Audit an Individual Library or List in SharePoint](https://www.ultimatewindowssecurity.com/blog/default.aspx?p=75852ef4-3c49-4948-879d-52fc2cb01337)

Answer (score 1):

To configure auditing for a particular document library you have mentioned the right thing - "Information Management Policy Settings".

Enabling auditing at site-collection level would enable for all document libraries, lists, and content types.

Comment: so it is not mandatory to enable auditing at site collection level, before enabling at document library level?